# Is there any tool for monitoring Memory Management?

Tags: android, android-testing

I know we can check in android studio itself, but i want separate tool for 
testing.please can any one suggest what are the tools are available for test for android app performance....

Answer (score 1):

in android studio ide there is some tools for that.You can check with profiler in android studio,etc

[References](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate Firebase Performance SDK in you app for **App Performance**.This SDK collect performance data from your app, then review and analyze that data in the Firebase console
Refere :[Firebase Performance Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `Profiler` in Android Studio.

[More](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)